# Login/Logout a user using Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a project with Django. I am trying to implement the ability of login and logout a user from the application using only python scripts in order to send post request from the client to the server.
I am trying to logout a user from my application but it does not seems to work. In my login function this is the method used to login a user:

```
    # Function for user's login
    @csrf_exempt
    def loginUser(request):
        login_user = authenticate(username=user.customer_username, password=user.customer_password)
        if login_user is not None:
            if login_user.is_active:
                request.session.set_expiry(86400)
                login(request, login_user)
                print(request.user.is_active)
    http_response = HttpResponse()
    return http_response
```

The result of the print is True here which means that the login method is correct if I am not wrong. When I try to logout the user, using this method:

```
    # Function for user's logout
    @csrf_exempt
    def logoutUser(request):
        # Loging out the user
        print(request.user.is_active)
        logout(request)
    http_response = HttpResponse()
    return http_response
```

It does not logout the user and the result of the print is False here, which means that the user is not logged in. If anyone have any idea, how to solve this, it would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: [`is_active`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) shows whether or not an account is considered active. That's not the same as whether or not the account is currently logged in or not.

Comment: @Alasdair tried is_authenticated as well before and after logout(request) and it is still false.

Comment: Did you consider to use the Django views for login and logout? Why invent the wheel? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views

Comment: *tried is_authenticated as well before and after logout(request)* - it's not clear to me what you tried. You haven't said what version of Django you are using. And `password=user.customer_password` shouldn't work because the password is not stored in plain text. It would be much better to use the built in `login` and `logout` views as allcaps suggests.

Comment: `password=user.customer_password` - that shouldn't work because the password is not stored in plain text.

Comment: @Alasdair it is working since it gets the password which is provided from the post request. I will have a look on how to use the built in functions of Django. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer for this problem. Because I was using a python script to send and receive post requests between the server and the client, the current user which was logged in was not saved due to after the request from the client the connection between client and server stoped. So by initialising a global [Session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object and later use that object to make request it allowed me to persist certain parameters across requests.
This is the code I used in the client side in order to make requests:

```
import requests
from requests import Session
# Create the Json object for the login
data = {'username': username,
        'password': password}
r = requests.Session()
login_response = r.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login", data=data)
logout_response = r.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/logout")
```

And this is the code I used in the server side:

```
# Function for user's login
@csrf_exempt
def loginUser(request):
    # Get the username and password from the post request
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    login_user = authenticate(username=username, 
                                 password=password)
    if login_user is not None:
        if login_user.is_active:
            login(request, login_user)
            http_response = HttpResponse()
    return http_response


# Function for user's logout
@csrf_exempt
def logoutUser(request):
    # Loging out the user
    logout(request)
    http_response = HttpResponse()
    return http_response
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Commenting for visibility, Kyriakos, this is completely correct.
I also am trying to query Django by logging in and out using Django Auth (django.contrib.auth) but using a custom python script to test the posts of API's when logging in. Without the global request sessions the django.contrib.auth login will always show Anonymous User when attempting to use request.user, and this is the culprit.

```
import requests
from requests import Session

r = requests.Session() #SETTING GLOBAL SESSION FOR DJANGO TO READ MY SESSION

x = r.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/newsagency/api/login/', {'username':'jake', 'password':'UOL'})
print("login response: ", x.text)


x = r.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/newsagency/api/poststory/', {'headline' :'Story 1',
                                                                   'category' : 'pol',
                                                                   'region' : 'w',
                                                                   'details' : 'some details'})
print("post story response: ", x.text)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def LogIn(request):
if request.method=="POST":
    loginname = request.POST["name"]  
    loginemail = request.POST['Email']
    loginpassword = request.POST["Password"]  
    user = authenticate(username=loginname, email=loginemail, password=loginpassword)
```

@login_required()
def signout(request):
logout(request)
return redirect(index)